# Make R exit with non-zero status code

Tags: r, exit

I am looking for the R equivalent of linux/POSIX exit(n) which will halt the process with exit code n, signaling to a parent process that an error had occurred.  Does R have such a facility?

Comment: The builtin function `quit(` can take multiple different kinds of numeric arguments, so you have to be more explicit.  Use: `quit(status=3)` and see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's an argument to `quit()`.  See `?quit`.

*Arguments*:

```
status: the (numerical) error status to be returned to the operating
        system, where relevant.  Conventionally ‘0’ indicates
        successful completion.
```

*Details*:

```
 Some error statuses are used by R itself.  The default error
 handler for non-interactive use effectively calls ‘q("no", 1,
 FALSE)’ and returns error code 1.  Error status 2 is used for R
 ‘suicide’, that is a catastrophic failure, and other small numbers
 are used by specific ports for initialization failures.  It is
 recommended that users choose statuses of 10 or more.
```

Comment: Documentation link: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html. Example: `quit(save = "no", status = 1, runLast = FALSE)`

Answer (score 11):

```
quit(status=1)
```

Replace `1` by whatever exit code you need.