# Rscript with Runtime.getRuntime.exec - exitvalue is not 0

Tags: java, r

I am trying to run a very simple r-script from within Java.
The code in the script is really simple:

```
x = cbind(1,2,3).
```

I am calling

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript /home/folder1/folder2/my.r")
```

And...well:

```
 try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" Rscript /home/folder1/folder2/my.r");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Starter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
System.out.println("Started");
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Starter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
if( p.exitValue() != 0 )

    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
else 
    System.out.println("Finished");
```

I get the print "Started" and then I get "sth wrong".

If I understand that correctly that means the rscript is found but cannot work?
With THAT code in it?

How can that be?

Comment: Have you tried running the `Rscript` from the command line?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681199/make-r-exit-with-non-zero-status-code

Comment: I did, I do not see how that has any connection

Comment: Exitvalue is 1, however.

Comment: I am using that SAME command at another place in my program where it does work. However, at that other place I am calling a script within my project folder, HERE I am trying to call a skript in my home directory. Can it be that this i snot possible within a Java project?