# Run R script from Python using OS module

Tags: python, r, operating-system

I'm trying to run a simple script in R from Python using `os.chdir()` and `os.system()`.  I am able to run the code from the Windows command prompt, so I didn't think running it from Python would be an issue.  My R program is located at `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/i386` and the R script is at `C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/script.R` so my Python function looks like this:

```
def runScript():
    os.chdir('C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/i386')
    returnCode = os.system('R --vanilla < C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/script.R')
    print returnCode
    return
```

This doesn't do what I want it to do, and returns a return code of 1.  Any thoughts?

P.S. When I change the directory in the windows command prompt to the one above, and run `R --vanilla < C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/script.R`, it works just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with

```
def runScript():
    os.chdir('')
    returnCode = os.system(r'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/i386/R --vanilla < C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/script.R')
    print returnCode
    return returnCode
```

?

Comment: It flashes the windows command prompt very quickly, then returns 1 as before.  I do a lot of system calls to executable C programs, I'm not sure why this one isn't working the way I'd like.

Comment: os.system has been deprecated. Try using subprocess python module. subprocess.call is the function that you are looking for

Comment: subprocess.call('C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/i386/R --vanilla < C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/script.R', shell=True)

Comment: I am still getting a return code of 1 using subprocess as you described.  I'll operate under the assumption that I'm doing something wrong and get back to you to let you know what it was.  Thanks for your help @praveen

Comment: It's briefly (less than 1 second) opening R in a windows command prompt then closing out without ever having run my actual R script. Then it returns 1.  Any thoughts?

Comment: are you able to run "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/i386/R " successfully in the command prompt? Open your command prompt and see if you can run the complete command successfully

Comment: Yes, this path with the quotations opens R in my command prompt

Comment: R --vanilla < path.R has spaces in it.  Do I need to add extra quotes somewhere in Python to make it execute properly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [os.system documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) :

> on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit status of the command run

This means your R script certainly exits with the command "exit(1)" or has an error which is handled by the [default error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681213/1113348) of R interpreter.

Comment: I believe I must have an error somewhere, I think the 1 is coming from Python telling me it couldn't do what I wanted it to do.  This is weird..