# STOP the execution but not generating the output as an "ERROR" in R

Tags: r, bash, error-handling, stdout, stderr

Which statement that I can use to substitute a stop() statement in R?
The reason why I want to substitute a stop() statement is that it generates an error instead of a message. So I want something that I can stop the execution but not generating the output as an error . Thank you!

```
if (nrow(new_data) == 0) {
    message(log_date, " - ","no new_data is found ")
    opt <- options(show.error.messages=FALSE)
    on.exit(options(opt))
    stop()

}
else { # DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

So, if I run **echo $?** on terminal after running this script, I got a **"1"** instead of **"0"**. But I want a "0" because this is an expected output, not a true error.

Comment: would `break` work?

Comment: Use `try` or `tryCatch` to give you greater controll.

Comment: how about `quit(save="no",status=0)`?

Comment: (Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7681199/3358272)