# Exit code when calling R script from bash

Tags: r, bash, macos, rscript

I have an R script that I call from an interactive bash shell (MacOS Catalina). This is one of a series of scripts that I call from the interactive shell, so I need to know if the initial script failed. It seems that no matter how the script fails (assert_that, stop, stopfinot, quit), R always returns an exit status of 0. How can I return a non-zero exist status from a failed R script?

Here is an example R script (fail.r).

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

#library(assertthat)

message("Starting script")

#assert_that(FALSE)

#stop('Fail')

#stopifnot(FALSE)

q(save="no", status=10, runLast=FALSE)

message("Should not reach here")
```

And here is how I might call it from a bash prompt

```
src/poc/fail.r

echo $?
```

Regardless of the method I use to exit the R script $? always returns 0.

A couple other posts address this issue, but do not seem to apply to my situation ([How to get an Rscript to return a status code in non-interactive bash mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589407/how-to-get-an-rscript-to-return-a-status-code-in-non-interactive-bash-mode)) and ([Make R exit with non-zero status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681199/make-r-exit-with-non-zero-status-code))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get the status from Rscript back to the calling shell (R version 4.0.2, bash version 3.2.57 or zsh version 5.8 running on a MacBook Pro, macOS Mohave 10.14.6) using `q(status = N)`. To get non-zero exit status from a failed R script, use `q(status = 2)` or higher, see [`quit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html):

```
$ Rscript -e 'q(status = 0);'
$ echo $?
0

$ Rscript -e 'q(status = 2);'
$ echo $?
2

$ Rscript -e 'q(status = 10);'
$ echo $?
10

$ R --version
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)

$ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0)
```

Using a script essentially identical to the one you posted, I get the expected results (the status from `quit` is passed successfully to the enclosing shell):

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

message("Starting script")
## Use status = 0, 2 or 10:
q(save = "no", status = 2, runLast = FALSE)
message("Should not reach here")
```

Output (tested with zsh and bash versions shown above):

```
$ ~/test/test1.r
Starting script
$ echo $?       
0
$ ~/test/test1.r
Starting script
$ echo $?       
2
$ ~/test/test1.r
Starting script
$ echo $?       
10
```

**SEE ALSO:**

> Some error status values are used by R itself. The default error
> handler for non-interactive use effectively calls q("no", 1, FALSE)
> and returns error status 1. Error status 2 is used for R ‘suicide’,
> that is a catastrophic failure, and other small numbers are used by
> specific ports for initialization failures. It is recommended that
> users choose statuses of 10 or more.
>
> Valid values of status are system-dependent, but 0:255 are normally
> valid.

*(From [`quit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html) docs)*

Comment: Thanks @Timur your example helped me figure out what was wrong. Rscript was running .Rprofile, which loaded a bunch of packages and set some options. Something in there must have been preventing quit status from coming back. When I did Rscript --vanilla the quit status was returned correctly.

Rscript --vanilla -e 'q(status = 2);'
echo $?

This also worked when calling a script using shebang: #!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla

Comment: @BenCarlson I am glad that my answer was helpful! I recommend to make your comment into an answer, and accept your own answer (and thus un-accept my answer in the process). Your answer would help future users debug similar issues. It did not occur to me that `.Rprofile` and `Rscript --vanilla` were the key to the answer. I will keep my answer posted, of course, since it could be helpful to others as well. :)