# How to combine R script, IF statement, and Pause code?

Tags: r, batch-file, if-statement

I am running a batch file (.bat) to run an R script which works fine. My batch file is ran daily with my task manager. What I am trying to do now is figure out how to `pause` my batch file if the condition in R script stops the R script.

My batch file:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\Rscript.exe" C:\Auto_R_Reports\Codes\SICK_WTGs.R
```

My R script:

```
if(NROW(Sick_WTG_USA) == 0){
    stop('NO SICK WTGs')
} else {source("./Codes/2WKcheck.R")}
```

The idea is that when the if condition in R script evaluates true and my R script stops, I also want my batch file to `pause` so that I know it stopped and paused.

Comment: Pause until when? You want to press a button for example and it continues?

Comment: See [Make R exit with non-zero status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681199/) and let your R script quit with a non-zero exit code like `1` and append in batch file at end of `rscript.exe` command line `|| pause` or add as next line `if errorlevel 1 pause`. See also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

Comment: Or if your R script outputs a specific error string to standard output you could also append on `rscript.exe` command line `| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "error string" >nul && pause`. But the first option with non-zero exit code on an error is definitely the better solution.

Comment: Thanks @Mofi, that work for me, both answers.