# Exit Powershell if R errors

Tags: r, powershell

I have a series of R files I'm calling in powershell. If one errors, I don't want it to carry on to try running the subsequent R scripts. The problem I have is capturing the R error in powershell, and using this to terminate the script. Any ideas?

I've tried this so far to no avail, as the error isn't being caught.

**Powershell script:**

```
# loop some scripts, try running them and if they fail then stop the process
foreach ($element in @(1,2,3)) { 
  Write-Host $element
  try{
    # minimal working eg of a script that stops early
    Rscript -e  "stop('error')"
  } 
  catch {
    Write-Host 'Rscript failed on run' $element'. Process killed in 10 seconds'
    Start-Sleep 10
    Exit 
  }
}
```

As it doesn't capture the error, the output message is:

```
1
Error: error
Execution halted
2
Error: error
Execution halted
3
Error: error
Execution halted
```

Any suggestions would be great! Thank you

EDIT:

Based off of the comment, am using this now (for future reference):

```
foreach ($element in @(1,2,3)) { 
  Write-Host $element
  # minimal working eg of a script that stops early
  Rscript -e  "stop('error')"
  if ($LastExitCode -ne 0){
    Write-Host 'Rscript failed on run' $element'. Process killed in 10 seconds'
    Start-Sleep 10
    Exit 
  }
}
```

---

Comment: [Make R exit with non-zero status code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7681199/1701026) and use [`$LastExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#lastexitcode)

Comment: Ah thank you, this is perfect. I couldn't find the right words to put in Google to get an answer like this, was doing my head in :p. You can add this as an answer if you like and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are only available in the scope of the RScript not thrown into the PowerShell environment. You might consider to redirect the display output and evaluate the text but using the [`$LastExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#lastexitcode) is probably easiest.

<sub>(I don't have RScript installed but guess you can just capture the output like: `$Result = Rscript -e  "stop('error')"`.)</sub>

The `exitcode` can be controlled by the `Status` property of the [`Quit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html) command and is apparently automatically set on a `stop('error')`:

```
foreach ($element in @(1,2,3)) { 
  Write-Host $element
  # minimal working eg of a script that stops early
  Rscript -e  "stop('error')"
  if ($LastExitCode -ne 0){
    Write-Host 'Rscript failed on run' $element'. Process killed in 10 seconds'
    Start-Sleep 10
    Exit 
  }
}
```